# I want to display only the sentences of the passed id on the screen

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Template Language question. I want to pass the ID of the sentence I want to the url and display only the sentence of the passed ID on the screen.
url:

```
path('sentenceCard/<str:listName>/<int:listId>/', views.sentenceCard, name='sentenceCard')
```

views.py:

```
def sentenceCard(request, listName, listId):
    sentence = Sentence.objects.filter(Classification=listName)
    return render(request, 'english_note/sentenceCard.html', {'sentences':sentence, 'listId': listId})
```

html:

```
    <a href='#'>{{sentences.0.korean_sentence}}<br>
    <a href='#'>{{sentences.1.korean_sentence}}<br>
```

Variables in Template Variables?
like this?
`{{sentences.listId.korean_sentence}}`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the sentence. Something like the following if I'm understanding your setup. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) on `url` builtin tag.

```
{% for sentence in sentences %}
    <a href='{% url 'sentenceCard' listName=sentence.classification listId=listId  %}'>{{ sentence.korean_sentence }}</a><br />
{% endfor %}
```

You may need to prefix the url path name with your app name:
`{% url 'yourapp:sentenceCard' listName=....%}`

Not asked for, but a suggestion or two which may make your Django coding easier:

- lowercase your fields. `Classification` becomes `classification`
- use `def sentence_card(request, list_name, list_id):`
- when filtering, name your queryset with a plural: `sentences = Sentence.objects.filter(classification=list_name)`
- when possible context variables mimic the object `{'sentences':sentences}`

None is absolutely to make the code work, but when trouble shooting later, it is nice to know by case what sort of thing you are dealing with. In Django in particular, it will help when you start doing some advanced filtering by never having to check how you named a field. Knowing the uppercased thing is the class, and the lower cased version is the instance will also come in handy.

Comment: I want only one display sentence. I am not good at English .. @AMG